# Javascript JSON parse function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, function, callback, return

I have a fuction ***`request.send();`*** that parses a `.json` file, and gets `credits` by current `steamid`

```
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

request.open('GET', './players.json');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
    var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      if(items[i].steamid == currentSteamID)
      {
        playerCredits = parseFloat(items[i].credits);
        alert(playerCredits);
        return playerCredits;
      }
    }
  }
}

var playerCredits = request.send();
alert(playerCredits);
```

---

The *first alert* works fine:

[image: First Alert]

---

I want to use the credits later, that is why I assigned the function to a variable:

```
var playerCredits = request.send();
```

But alerting `playerCredits` give me this:

[image: Second Alert]

---

By searching for similiar questions I found out that I needed to use *Callback*, I tried doing this:

```
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open('GET', './players.json');
request.onreadystatechange = function(callback) {
  if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
    var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      if(items[i].steamid == currentSteamID)
      {
        playerCredits = parseFloat(items[i].credits);
        callback(playerCredits);   
      }
   }
 }
}

request.send(function() {
   console.log(playerCredits);
});
```

However this is the error I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

I'm pretty sure I'm not using *Callback* as I'm supposed to, and now I ask you:

**What needs to be changed for this to work?**

Comment: there are many inconsistencies in your code, you seem to be new to JavaScript. I recommend you to lookup for the exact meaning of important keywords such as Callback, XHR. Wikipedia is a good place for that. I could probably answer, but how many times will you stop by again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a function into the `.send` function *does **not** pass it into the `onreadystatechange` function*.

You can take advantage of closures by declaring your `callback` function outside of `onreadystatechange`.

```
var request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

// Declare the function here
function callback(playerCredits) {
    console.log(playerCredits);
    // Do other awesome stuff here
}

request.open('GET', './players.json');
request.onreadystatechange = function(callback) {
    if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
        var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].steamid == currentSteamID) {
                var playerCredits = parseFloat(items[i].credits);

                // It is still in scope here.
                callback(playerCredits);   
            }
        }
    }
}

request.send();
```

---

**Notes:**

- If I were you, I'd instead take advantage of the vast array of JavaScript libraries out there that have already dealt with all of this. I'd look into [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) if I were you (I have no affiliation with jQuery).

  This is what your code would look like if you used jQuery:

  ```
  function callback(playerCredits) {
      console.log(playerCredits);
      // Do other awesome stuff here
  }

  $.ajax('./players.json', {
      complete: function(response) {
          var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
              if(items[i].steamid == currentSteamID) {
                  var playerCredits = parseFloat(items[i].credits);

                  // It is still in scope here.
                  callback(playerCredits);   
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- I used `console.log(playerCredits);` instead of `alert(playerCredits)` because it is more versatile. If you `console.log` an object in most browsers you will see an expansion of the object (rather than `[object Object]` as you would get from an `alert`). (See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers))
- I refactored your `request` declaration with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- I declared `playerCredits` using the `var` keyword to keep it within function scope of the `onreadystate` function. Declaring it without using `var` makes it an automatically global variable.

---

**Further Reading:**

- [Pass arguments into ajax onreadystatechange callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582663/pass-arguments-into-ajax-onreadystatechange-callback)

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
request.onreadystatechange = ...
```

what comes after the `=` **is** the callback

what comes in those paranteses is maybe an event object
but you will find everything you need in your `request` object. So your callback function doesn't need any parameters.

Having `callback(playerCredits);` doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

I don't know exactly what you want to do exactly. A callback is a function that is called back after a certain event occurs.

Read this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange is an event handler, in other words, a function that is called each time an event is invoked, in this case - the state of the request has been changed.

Quoting this answer: [What is a callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function)

> A callback function is a function which is:
>
> - passed as an argument to another function, and,
> - is invoked after some kind of event.

They both achieve the same thing, just a difference in how they are passed to the interpreter.

Send function is a void function, and that means it does not return any value. So assigning your send function to a variable means nothing, if you want to use the response got then you have to assign request.responseText to a variable, but only after we got the response, and that means in the event handler.

You might want to look into this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest .

But you will almost never use the native javascript to send your ajax requests, 
jQuery is a libary that helps you do these kind of things with ease: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ .